# Using explode and implode on associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array structure...

```
 Array
(
    [old] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 121
            [cod] => SS
            [tabl] => ss
        )

    [new] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 123
            [cod] => CC
            [tabl] => cc
        )

    [not] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 142
            [cod] => NN
            [tabl] => nn
        )
)
```

And what I want to achieve was to get the following...

foreach sub array read [cod] and get like this (SS,CC,NN) and then use it in switch like

$a = $_POST['cod'];

switch ($a)
foreach (those (SS,CC,NN)) {

case 'SS':
do some thing.
break;

But what I can't achieve from the above is I can't get the those three sub-array (SS,CC,NN) in this model.

```
$codes = array (SS,CC,NN) or like

      Array
            (
                [cod] => SS
                [cod] => CC
                [cod] => NN
            )
```

How do I achieve that, Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($your_array as $row) {
  $result[] = $row['cod'];
}
// $result = array('SS','CC','NN');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.5, then you can use [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$result = array_column($myArrayRecords, 'cod');
```